# Show Ad after each completed level

Tags: android, admob

I am building a bubble shooter Android game and I'm stuck on displaying AdMob ads after each completed level.

Details:
After I play a level, a screen is displayed with the message **You won** or **You lost** and I have 2 buttons: The first one is **continue playing** and the other one is **go back home**.

I want to display an interstitial ad after I press **continue playing**. Right now, only if I press **go back home** the interstitial ad comes up.

Here is the code I am using:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_page_activity);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);

this.admob = new Admob(this, "MyAdMobID");

@Override
public void onLevelUp() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLevelUp");

    if(admob != null){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try{
                    admob.loadAd();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try{
                    Intent i = new Intent(instance, WonActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is the Admob.java class:

```
public class Admob extends AdListener{

private Activity ctx;

//Admob
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
private AdRequest adRequest;

private String unitId;

public static boolean fromAdmob = false;

public Admob(Activity ctx, String unitId)
{
    this.ctx    = ctx;
    this.unitId = unitId;

    try{
        this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this.ctx);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId(unitId);

        interstitial.setAdListener(this);
        adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void loadAd()
{
    try{
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onAdLoaded() {
    try{
        fromAdmob = true;
        interstitial.show();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: what is the answer, I do not get it

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the admob.java class too.

Comment: Here is the exact example you want: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd.html)

Comment: Move pretty much all the code in your constructor to loadAd() except the bit you assign context and unitId. You're building the ad in the wrong place. <rant>As an aside, why do we developers hate our users so much? :) The interstitial ads are so annoying, specially if you have to deal with them too often</rant>.

Comment: Good point, I would prefer to show an interstitial ad after 5 levels for example, but I need to show it first in the right place :(

Comment: Put in a break point in the `onAdLoaded` (or some log message) and see if it ever gets called. It may have failed loading the ad for some reason. Do this next to moving the code to the correct place (my previous comment) and see if anything obvious pops up.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly has to be moved. And I still don't understand why when I press the Home button the ad is shown and when I press Play it doesn't show :(

Comment: Just copy/paste the code from the link @Harry pasted. That should work for you.

Comment: So I should paste the code that @Harry posted in my Admob.java file?